# How can I build the PackageInstaller source code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, packageinstaller

I've cloned packageInstaller source code from [PackageInstaller Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/). The project needs [NDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) to build but has no Application.mk file. The android.mk file contains these codes:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    android-support-v4 \
    android-support-annotations \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v7-preference \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-v14-preference \
    android-support-v17-preference-leanback \
    android-support-v17-leanback \
    SettingsLib

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    xz-java

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := PackageInstaller
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

# Comment for now unitl all private API dependencies are removed
# LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := system_current

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

ifeq (PackageInstaller,$(LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME))
# Use the following include to make our test apk.
ifeq (,$(ONE_SHOT_MAKEFILE))
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
endif
endif
```

I had some trouble to build this project, since it has no application.mk files. Now I have two major problem with this project:

1. How can I add dependencies which are mentioned in the android.mk file?
2. How can i build the entire project successfully?

Comment: `PackageInstaller` isn't a project. It is a part of a firmware build. I will be *very* surprised if it can be built as a separate app, outside of building an entire firmware.

Comment: @CommonsWare But as you see [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/) , it's a part of android system apps, so I think it could be built alone.

Comment: Very little at https://android.googlesource.com can be built as ordinary standalone apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare So is there any official tutorial to how to build the android firmware?

Comment: You might start at https://source.android.com/setup

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to download it, but is it required to download the whole Android source code, because it's about 250GB and needs additional 150GB to build, that is so much huge!